# Why is this process of calculating eigenvalues wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $X$ is an eigenvector of $A$ and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

$AX$=$\lambda X$

Now suppose there is a matrix $Y$ such as $XY = I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. Then

$AXY = \lambda XY$ and so $AI = \lambda I$ and so by equality of matrices one can determine the eigenvalues of $A$.

But this must be wrong. Because in this case, the eigenvalues will only be the diagonal entries of $A$. Where is the mistake in this method?

The dimensions of $A, X$ amd  $Y$ are $n\times n, n\times 1$ and  $1\times n$.

Comment: What could be the dimensions of $Y$?

Comment: If $X$ is a vector, $XY=I$ does not hold.

Comment: If $X$ is a column-matrix with at least $2$ entries, there cannot exist a matrix $Y$ such that $XY = I$

Comment: $X$ is a vector, so $XY=I$ is not possible.

Comment: In particular, the image of $XY$ is one-dimensional. So $XY=I$ is only possible when $n=1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Why is it not possible?

Comment: @BenGrossmann If X is 2 by 1 and  Y is 1 by 2, then wouldn't $XY=I$ be possible?

Comment: Just look at a simple example. Let $X = (2, 3)$. Can you tell us what $Y$ would be such that $XY = I$?

Comment: @Asif The rank of $XY$ would necessarily be $1$, but $I$ has a rank of $2$.

Comment: Given an vector ($n\times 1$ matrix) $V$, then image $(XY)V=X(YV)$ and $YV$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix, a scalar, so $(XY)V$ is a scalara multiple of $X$. If $XY=I$ then $(XY)V=V.$ So the scalar multiples of $X$ must include all vectors, which means $n=1.$

Comment: @BenGrossmann Why would the rank of XY necessarily be 1?

Comment: @AsifIqubal For any vector $U$, we have $XYU = X(YU)$, which is a scalar multiple of $X$. In other words, the image of $XY$ is spanned by $X$ and is therefore one-dimensional.

Comment: @AsifIqubal Associative law of multiplication

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I understand. I had already deleted my comment. But I think it would be best if you give an answer. The community seems to discourage answering questions through comments.

Comment: @RobbytheBelgian I can't really tell what the exact vector will be. But a $1×2$ matrix will be able to give a $(2×1)×(1×2)=(2×2)$ identity matrix.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Can you please explain in an answer why it will not hold?

Comment: @Asif Iqubal Please try to work out what vector $Y = (a, b)$ will have $(3, 2)^T  (a, b) = I_2$. This is just a system of linear equations in two variables, so you should be able to find the solution, right? You say you should be able to. If it's possible, it shouldn't be hard. If you can't, have a look at the other comments and answers as to why.

Comment: @AsifIqubal: check the dimensionality of all your equations.

Comment: @YvesDaoust can you point out where my dimensionality is wrong?

Comment: Spend the minimum effort of writing the dimensions in the products.

Answer (score 1):

If $n>1,$ there is no such $Y.$

If $X$ is an $n\times 1$ matrix, and $Y$ is $1\times n$ matrix, then $XY$ cannot be the $n\times n$ identity.

That's because if $V$ is a vector (or $n\times 1$ matrix,) then $(XY)V=X(YV)$ and $YV$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix, or a scalar. If $XY=I$ then every $V=(XY)V=X(YV)$ must be a scalar multiple of $X$, which is only possible if $n=1.$

---

Another way to see this is that $X,$ as an $n\times 1$ matrix, has rank one, so $XY$ has rank at most one for any compatible matrix $Y.$ But the identity matrix has rank $n.$

---

If you have $n$ independent eigenvectors $X_1,\dots,X_n$ for the same eigenvalue $\lambda$ you can solve $X_1Y_1+X_2Y_2+\cdots+X_nY_n=I$ and then you'd get $A=\lambda I.$

Comment: Andrew If $V$ is $n×1$, then $YV$ can be $1×1$ because $YV$ will be $(1×2)×(2×1)=(1×1)$. So I can't understand what forbids the existence of $1×2$ matrix $Y$ such that $XY=I$.

Comment: Sorry. I had made a mistake in my comment. I have corrected it.